# How to implement a button which sends a message periodically(User click only once) to another network ()e.g. CAN)

Tags: java, android

Hello I am new to Android Studio and Coding itself. I want to know how I can Implement a button which only on One click at UI, forward a package of Data periodically.. I have CAN network access basically I want to send a CAN message periodically.

I know the message type in CAN itself can be sent to Cyclic but due to  my project limitation that option is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TimerTask on button click action.

```
                new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //send your message here.
                    }
                },0,5*1000);
```

This timer will run every 5 second.

Answer (score 0):

**USE TIMER TASK to perform periodic operations**
Have a look at given code below:

```
 public void startSendingMessages() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
                // PERFORM OPERATION HERE
                // TO PERFORM UI Operations use Handler and pass LOOPER.getMainLooper() in param
            });
        }
    }, 0, 1000); // after 1000 milliseconds it will perform task again

}
```

> Dont forget to cancel timer in OnDestory()

```
timer.cancel();
```